# clang iostream - symbol not found

Tags: c++, linker, iostream, clang

So I'm trying to get the `clang` compiler to work.. my natural first choice of program was the following extremely complex code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;    using std::endl;
/* hello world.cpp */
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On the command line I did: `clang helloworld.cpp` and I get the following nice error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in cc-4iziZq.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in cc-4iziZq.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in cc-4iziZq.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in cc-4iziZq.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in cc-4iziZq.o
  "std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))", referenced from:
      _main in cc-4iziZq.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is wrong?
Thanks!
-kstruct

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`clang` is a C compiler.  You need to use `clang++` or use the `-x c++` flag.

Comment: Clearly I am not fully awake. -_- Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> clang is a C compiler. You need to use clang++ or use the -x c++ flag.

still need add **-lstdc++**.

I figured out this by **-v** option. And I found the diffrence is:

clang++

> -lstdc++
>   -lm
>   -lgcc_s
>   -lgcc
>   -lc
>   -lgcc_s
>   -lgcc

clang

> -lgcc
>   --as-needed
>   -lgcc_s
>   --no-as-needed
>   -lc
>   -lgcc
>   --as-needed
>   -lgcc_s
>   --no-as-needed